# how to install numpy in pycharm ( get error)

Tags: numpy, opencv, pycharm

I have python  3.6 and pip  9.0.3 i am trying ton install  `numpy` in  `pycharm`
 but it's show me message [I don't  know what i missed and to to fix it .I also  try by command prompt .but not solved my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9qPl.png)

Comment: What OS is this on?

Comment: i am using window 10

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have just one Python version installed, Try upgrading the pip utility `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Or,

If you have multiple Python installations, make sure you have PyCharm pointing to the Python you intend to use.

Ways to install numpy (or any python module):

1. Command Line: `pip install numpy`
2. Graphical (via PyCharm): File -> Settings -> Project -> Project Interpreter -> click on green  `+` icon -> search and select numpy -> Install Package